# How to handle constructors that must acquire multiple resources in an exception safe manner

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, c++-faq, delegating-constructor

I've got a non-trivial type that *owns* multiple resources.  How do I construct it in an exception safe manner?

For example, here is a demo class `X` that holds an array of `A`:

```
#include "A.h"

class X
{
    unsigned size_ = 0;
    A* data_ = nullptr;

public:
    ~X()
    {
        for (auto p = data_; p < data_ + size_; ++p)
            p->~A();
        ::operator delete(data_);
    }

    X() = default;
    // ...
};
```

Now the obvious answer for this particular class is to **use `std::vector<A>`**.  And that's good advice.  But `X` is only a stand-in for more complicated scenarios where `X` must own multiple resources and it isn't convenient to use the good advice of "use the std::lib."  I've chosen to communicate the question with this data structure simply because it is familiar.

To be *crystal* clear:  If you can design your `X` such that a defaulted `~X()` properly cleans everything up ("the rule of zero"), or if `~X()` only has to release a single resource, then that is best.  However, there are times in real life when `~X()` has to deal with multiple resources, and this question addresses those circumstances.

So this type already has a good destructor, and a good default constructor.  My question centers on a non-trivial constructor that takes two `A`'s, allocates space for them, and constructs them:

```
X::X(const A& x, const A& y)
    : size_{2}
    , data_{static_cast<A*>(::operator new (size_*sizeof(A)))}
{
    ::new(data_) A{x};
    ::new(data_ + 1) A{y};
}
```

I have a fully instrumented test class `A` and if no exceptions are thrown from this constructor it works perfectly well.  For example with this test driver:

```
int
main()
{
    A a1{1}, a2{2};
    try
    {
        std::cout << "Begin\n";
        X x{a1, a2};
        std::cout << "End\n";
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exceptional End\n";
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
A(int state): 1
A(int state): 2
Begin
A(A const& a): 1
A(A const& a): 2
End
~A(1)
~A(2)
~A(2)
~A(1)
```

I have 4 constructions, and 4 destructions, and each destruction has a matching constructor.  All is well.

However if the copy constructor of `A{2}` throws an exception, I get this output:

```
A(int state): 1
A(int state): 2
Begin
A(A const& a): 1
Exceptional End
~A(2)
~A(1)
```

Now I have 3 constructions but only 2 destructions.  The `A` resulting from `A(A const& a): 1` has been **leaked!**

One way to solve this problem is to lace the constructor with `try/catch`.  However this approach is not scalable.  After every single resource allocation, I need yet another nested `try/catch` to test the next resource allocation and deallocate what has already been allocated.  Holds nose:

```
X(const A& x, const A& y)
    : size_{2}
    , data_{static_cast<A*>(::operator new (size_*sizeof(A)))}
{
    try
    {
        ::new(data_) A{x};
        try
        {
            ::new(data_ + 1) A{y};
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            data_->~A();
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ::operator delete(data_);
        throw;
    }
}
```

This correctly outputs:

```
A(int state): 1
A(int state): 2
Begin
A(A const& a): 1
~A(1)
Exceptional End
~A(2)
~A(1)
```

But this is *ugly!*  What if there are 4 resources?  Or *400?!*  What if the number of resources is *not known at compile time?!*

Is there a *better* way?

Comment: Your code isn't correct. You never have to explicitly call a destructor. You should allocate `data_` via  `new []`, and destroy it via `delete[]`. That will call the destructors for you.

Comment: @EJP:  You miss the entire point of this post.  With this exact data structure, even `new/delete` is ridiculous.  This example is a simplistic example of more complex types that need to acquire multiple resources in a constructor.  If you need to do *exactly* what I show above, don't use this code, or `new/delete`.  **Use vector.**

Comment: My general guideline is, don't have objects with multiple responsibilities. Even dynamically-allocated memory is a responsibility, which can be delegated to `std::unique_ptr`. An object should either have a single responsibility, or form a single abstraction over a "product" of simple objects. In your case, you can easily create internal classes inside of `X` which have their own destructors to handle their unique responsibility.

Comment: @KABoissonneault:  That's a good guideline, and one I use regularly. But life can get complicated.  This post is about an under-appreciated technique for dealing with that complication.

Comment: Use one class to manage each resource, and then give your class multiple members of such class types.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Even if isolating the resource-management responsibility from class X is non-trivial, it is still the main problem, and **it** may well be worth a Stack Overflow post. Covering it up with more bad design (e.g. declaring a default constructor that may not have any valid meaning and just serves the purpose of ensuring the destructor gets called) is not a solution.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> Is there a *better* way?

**YES**

C++11 delivers a new feature called *delegating constructors* which deals with this situation *very* gracefully.  But it is a bit subtle.

The problem with throwing exceptions in constructors is to realize that the destructor of the object you're constructing doesn't run until the constructor is complete.  Though the destructors of sub objects (bases and members) will run if an exception is thrown, as soon as those sub objects are fully constructed.

The key here is to fully construct `X` *before* you start adding resources to it, and *then* add resources *one at a time*, keeping the `X` in a valid state as you add each resource.  Once the `X` is fully constructed, `~X()` will clean up any mess as you add resources.  Prior to C++11 this might look like:

```
X x;  // no resources
x.push_back(A(1));  // add a resource
x.push_back(A(2));  // add a resource
// ...
```

But in C++11 you can write the multi-resource-acquizition constructor like this:

```
X(const A& x, const A& y)
    : X{}
{
    data_ = static_cast<A*>(::operator new (2*sizeof(A)));
    ::new(data_) A{x};
    ++size_;
    ::new(data_ + 1) A{y};
    ++size_;
}
```

This is pretty much like writing code completely ignorant of exception safety.  The difference is this line:

```
    : X{}
```

This says:  Construct me a default `X`.  After this construction, `*this` is fully constructed and if an exception is thrown in subsequent operations, `~X()` gets run.  *This is revolutionary!*

Note that in this case, a default-constructed `X` acquires no resources.  Indeed, it is even implicitly `noexcept`.  So that part won't throw.  And it sets `*this` to a valid `X` that holds an array of size 0.  `~X()` knows how to deal with that state.

Now add the resource of the uninitialized memory.  If that throws, you still have a default constructed `X` and `~X()` correctly deals with that by doing nothing.

Now add the second resource:  A constructed copy of `x`.  If that throws, `~X()` will still deallocate the `data_` buffer, but without running any `~A()`.

If the second resource succeeds, set the `X` to a valid state by incrementing `size_` which is a `noexcept` operation.  If anything after this throws, `~X()` will correctly clean up a buffer of length 1.

Now try the third resource:  A constructed copy of `y`.  If that construction throws, `~X()` will correctly clean up your buffer of length 1.  If it doesn't throw, inform `*this` that it now owns a buffer of length 2.

Use of this technique *does not* require `X` to be default constructible.  For example the default constructor could be private.  Or you could use some other private constructor that puts `X` into a resourceless state:

```
: X{moved_from_tag{}}
```

In C++11, it is generally a good idea if your `X` can have a resourceless state as this enables you to have a `noexcept` move constructor which comes bundled with all kinds of goodness (and is the subject of a different post).

C++11 delegating constructors is a very good (scalable) technique for writing exception safe constructors as long as you have a resource-less state to construct to in the beginning (e.g. a noexcept default constructor).

Yes, there are ways of doing this in C++98/03, but they aren't as pretty.  You have to create an implementation-detail base class of `X` that contains the destruction logic of `X`, but not the construction logic.  Been there, done that, I love delegating constructors.

Comment: Whoops, I just realized I was preaching to the choir :) Would it be possible to update your question such that the problem is a bit more obvious? This problem here can be solved with C++ 98/03 in an elegant manner by just adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle (see my answer below).

I am afraid in this case delegating constructors help ease the pain enough that they end up hiding the main problem: the solution architecture.

Comment: This solution is no different than having data_ a `std::vector<A>`, using `data_.reserve(2)` instead of the manual allocation and `data_.push_back(...)` instead of the placement new and `++size`. This works without having the delegate constructor and even works without the need of a default constructor for X at all. (even works without the need for c++11 but personally I don't care about that since why wouldn't one use c++14 even, since it's already 2016 now) The solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38782850/1660116 is therefore equivalent to yours, just more maintainable and flexible.

Comment: I'm still not convinced this is any better than a couple of classes which deal with one resource each, but that *is* clever hijacking of a delegating constructor (and its corresponding destructor). I'll trust you on the actual existence of cases where that is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks to Francesco Giacomini (http://stackoverflow.com/users/4377355/francesco-giacomini) for spotting a type-o in this answer and trying to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem stems from a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle: Class X has to deal with managing the lifetimes of multiple objects (and that is probably not even its main responsibility).

The destructor of a class should only free the resources that the class has directly acquired. If the class is just a composite (i.e. an instance of the class owns instances of other classes) it should ideally rely on automatic memory management (via RAII) and just use the default destructor. If the class has to manage some specialized resources manually (e.g. opens a file descriptor or a connection, acquires a lock or allocates memory) I would recommend factoring out the responsibility of managing those resources to a class dedicated for this purpose and then using instances of that class as members.

Using the standard template library would in fact help because it contains data structures (such as smart pointers and `std::vector<T>`) that exclusively handle this problem. They can also be composed, so even if your X has to contain multiple instances of objects with complicated resource acquisition strategies, the problem of resource management in an exception safe manner is solved both for each member as well as for the containing composite class X.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, maybe try something like this:

```
#include "A.h"
#include <vector>

class X
{
    std::vector<A> data_;

public:
    X() = default;

    X(const A& x, const A& y)
        : data_{x, y}
    {
    }

    // ...
};
```